# How to convert a matrix as string to ndarray?

Tags: pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a csv file with this structure:

```
id;matrix
1;[[1.2 1.3] [1.2 1.3] [1.2 1.3]]
```

I'm trying read the matrix field as `numpy.ndarray` using `pandas.read_csv` to read and making `df.to_numpy()` to convert the matrix, but the `shape` array result in (1,0). I was waiting for the `shape` equals (3,2) as:

```
matrix = [[1.2 1.3] 
          [1.2 1.3]
          [1.2 1.3]]
```

I was try too `numpy.asmatrix`, but the result is like `df.to_numpy()`

Comment: is the matrix col and actual list or a string? Also, you are missing your commas in the list

Comment: That is a `str` display of a numpy array, which isn't intended for parsing.  You have to convert it to the string format of a list of lists, and `eval` that.  Handling that can be done, but it's messy.

Comment: You will also likely have to specify the seperater as a space rather than a comma.

Comment: testing with `test=eval(str('[[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]]'))`, have a syntax error, @hpaulj. Is that what you meant?

Comment: `eval('[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]')` is proper python.  Note the commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A solution with `pandas`

- Providing the format of the `matrix` column is consistent with that shown in the example, replace the spaces with `,`, then use `literal_eval` to turn the string into a list of lists, and then apply `np.array`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval
import numpy as np

# read the data
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')

# replace the spaces
df['matrix'] = df['matrix'].str.replace(' ', ',')

# apply literal_eval
df['matrix'] = df['matrix'].apply(literal_eval)

# apply numpy array
df['matrix'] = df['matrix'].apply(np.array)

print(type(df.iloc[0, 1]))

>>> numpy.ndarray
```

- Each row of the matrix column will be an `ndarray`
- The two apply calls can be combined into:

  - `df['matrix'] = df['matrix'].apply(lambda x: np.array(literal_eval(x)))`
- Or this hot mess:

  - `df['matrix'] = df['matrix'].str.replace(' ', ',').apply(lambda x: np.array(literal_eval(x)))`
  - I personally prefer one transformation per line for code clarity.